# c# contains word exception number

Tags: c#, string

I need to search a string and see if it contains  `"<addnum(x)>"`

I have used .contains on the other words that i searched for and the easiest way i could think for is you somehow could make exception for numbers or do you need to use another code for that?

My code this far.

```
public List<string> arguments = new List<string>();

    public void Custom_naming(string name_code)
    {
        arguments.Add("Changing the name to " + name_code); // Sets the new name.

        if( name_code.Contains("<addnum>") ) 
        {
            Add_number();
        }

        if (name_code.Contains("<addnum(x)>"))
        {// X = any number.
        }
    }
    private void Add_number() 
    {
        arguments.Add("Replaces all <addnum> with a number");
    }

    private void Add_number(int zeros) 
    {
        arguments.Add("Replaces all <addnumxx> with a number with lentgh of");
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to search for "<addnum(x)>" in a given string with "x" being an integer number?

Comment: To expand on @ataravati's comment, can `x` contain anything that is not strictly digits? For example, a decimal point.

Comment: Please clarify: do you need to handle cases like `<addnum(1.2)>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use a regular expression:

```
var match = Regex.Match(name_code, @"<addnum(?:\((\d+)\))?>");
if (match.Success)
{
    int zeros;
    if (int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out zeros))
    {
        Add_number(zeros);
    }
    else
    {
        Add_number();
    }
}
```

This will return invoke the appropriate `Add_number` method if `name_code` contains `<addnum>` or anything like `<addnum(123)>`.

If there could possibly be more than one such in `name_code`, e.g. `<addnum(1)><addnum(2)>`, you'll want to use a loop to analyze each match, like this:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(name_code, @"<addnum(?:\((\d+)\))?>");
foreach(var match in matches)
{
    int zeros;
    if (int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out zeros))
    {
        Add_number(zeros);
    }
    else
    {
        Add_number();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work for integers, but not for decimal numbers. The OP wasn't very clear about that part IMO.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling OP's `Add_number` method takes an `int`. I could be wrong, but I believe that's what was intended.

Comment: That `int` seems to me to be to be a length, for zero-padding or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Use regular expression:

```
string s = "Foo <addnum(8)> bar.";
var contains = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"<addnum\(\d+\)>");
```

If you want also extract number:

```
string s = "Foo <addnum(42)> bar.";
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"<addnum\((\d+)\)>");
if (match.Success)
{
    // assume you have valid integer number
    var number = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: if `<addnum(81)>` is also valid, you should add a `+` after `\d`.

Comment: @TimS. ok, agree, changed. OP talked about number which specify number length, so I initially decided to have number length from 1 to 9 digits

Comment: `IsMatch` works more like `Contains` than `==`, unless you specify start and end codes. You don't need to include the `.*` at the ends of the pattern.

Comment: If decimal numbers are also considered a subset of "any number" this gets trickier, particularly with localization...